# Copy a column from one table into another table in BigQuery SQL.

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to copy a column from table a to table b, both tables have 8301 rows. table a has 3 columns ID, start date, end date, table b has 3 columns ID, start date, string. I want to move end date from table a to table b. ID and start date columns are 100% identical in both tables.

I am trying a join

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.START_DATE, T2.END_DATE, T1.STRING
FROM `TABLE_B` T1
JOIN `TABLE_A` T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
ORDER BY 1,2
```

but when I run this join I get a table with 34,000 rows.

All I want to do is to copy and paste the enddate column from table a to table b. The tables are sorted so that the correct end dates are already in the correct row position.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. Here is the solution.

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.START_DATE, T2.END_DATE, T1.STRING
FROM `TABLE_B` T1
JOIN `TABLE_A` T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID and T1.START_DATE = T2.START_DATE
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: Great that you found the solution! You can accept your own answer after 48 hours of posting it in your post